# How can I smooth the curvature of this shape?

Tags: modeling, smooth

I want to smooth the XY curvature of the following solid shape:

[image: Screen Shot]

If I add a subdivision surface modifier it gets smoothed in all directions, so the "steps" along the top edge get smoothed out too. If I add supporting geometry (loopcut and slide) to bring back the steps along the top edge I end up sharpening the curve also.

Without the subdivision modifier I can add vertical loop cuts to create more geometry, but then I have to manually move each new loop in the XY plane to a position that smooths the curve which is time consuming and highly error prone. I basically want to add more loopcuts in the vertical plane and have their position interpolated so that the curve becomes smoothed out.

What is the best way to do this in Blender?

Edit: For clarity, these are the "steps" along the top edge I'm referring to:
[image]

... And this is the curve that I want to smooth/add more geometry to so it doesn't look so angular.

[image]

Comment: hello do you have an image of what you want to achieve? what are the steps you are talking about?

Comment: @moonboots I've added an image to show the "steps" along the top edge I'm referring to.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this kind of topology:

[image]

Which will work fine with a *Curve* modifier:

[image]